# Pycharm - import class - receiving: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<mydirishere>

Tags: pycharm, python-import

I have two directories.
Directory named Dir1 has class definitions
Directory named Dir2 has the import statement: from Dir1.guitarClass import Guitar, ElectricGuitar, BassGuitar

Both directories have been set as "Mark directory as Namespace package"

I run the program from the Terminal. ---

(venv) xxxxxxxxxx@MacBook-Air eraseme % python "Dir2/knowyourguitar.py"

and receive this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/eraseme/Dir2/knowyourguitar.py", line 3, in 
from Dir1.guitarClass import Guitar, ElectricGuitar, BassGuitar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Dir1'

This is my screen shot of the Pycharm:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this issue in the wrong way, this has nothing to do with Pycharm.

Pycharm may have marked it as a namespace package, but that doesn't mean that it is a namespace package.

You may want to create a file named `__init__.py` under `Dir1`, that's how you make a directory into an importable module.